# Remastersys failed

Tags: remastersys

So I was running remastsys to create my own Ubuntu distro and I left while it was running. When I came back it was hibernating and when I tried to wake it up it wouldn't do anything it just stayed a black screen. I restarted and even after doing that whenever I run remastersys my screen goes black and won't respond. How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked if remastersys did create your respin? it might be trying to continue where it left off.

Comment: Yes and it wan't made

Comment: I think I'll try and reinstall it before I do anything else

Comment: use apt-get purge instead of apt-get remove to erase the config files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just had to reinstall it. Works fine now it made the iso and didn't go to a black screen.